# Define a range using an existing named range & offset/resize

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use an existing named range to reference different rows (the columns should be the same). Right now I have the following:

```
Dim DetailONE, DetailONW, DetailW, DetailQc As Range
Set DetailONE = Sheet11.Range("CM12:EG13")
Set DetailONW = Sheet11.Range("EI12:GC13")
Set DetailW = Sheet11.Range("GE12:HO13")
Set DetailQc = Sheet11.Range("HQ12:IT13")
```

And then I refer to those named ranges but I get an Application defined or object defined error with the following. Does anyone know why? I don't know if I need the .Address part afterwards either or if I can forego this.

```
Dim OntarioWestDet, OntarioEastDet, WestDet, QuebecDet As Range
Set OntarioWestDet = Sheet11.Range(DetailONW.Address).Offset(3, 0).Resize(300, 0)
Set OntarioEastDet = Sheet11.Range(DetailONE).Offset(3, 0).Resize(300, 0)
Set WestDet = Sheet11.Range(DetailWe).Offset(3, 0).Resize(300, 0)
Set QuebecDet = Sheet11.Range(DetailQc).Offset(3, 0).Resize(300, 0)
```

Comment: Just use the variables `DetailONW.Offset(3, 0).Resize(300, 0)` and so on.

Comment: Also FWIW `Dim OntarioWestDet, OntarioEastDet, WestDet, QuebecDet As Range` only sets the last as a range and the rest as variants.  You need to do it one at a time: `Dim OntarioWestDet As Range, OntarioEastDet As Range, WestDet As Range, QuebecDet As Rang`

Comment: also FWIW, these are not "Named Ranges".  
They are range variables.  A named range is different and is tied to the workbook and thus is saved with the workbook.

Comment: In addition to @ScottCraner's points, I don't think the column parameter of 'Resize' can be zero so just omit, or use 1.

Comment: Even if I change the second section to: Dim OntarioWestDet As Range, OntarioEastDet As Range, WestDet As Range, QuebecDet As Range
Set OntarioWestDet = DetailONW.Offset(3).Resize(300, 1) it still gives me the same object error. Even if I change Resize(300,1) to Resize(300).

Comment: Sorry - I'm new to this website so I'm not sure how to make my code appear as code in a comment. @Scott

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (there is a typo in one of your names

```
Sub x()

Dim DetailONE As Range, DetailONW As Range, DetailW As Range, DetailQc As Range
Set DetailONE = Sheet11.Range("CM12:EG13")
Set DetailONW = Sheet11.Range("EI12:GC13")
Set DetailW = Sheet11.Range("GE12:HO13")
Set DetailQc = Sheet11.Range("HQ12:IT13")

Dim OntarioWestDet As Range, OntarioEastDet As Range, WestDet As Range, QuebecDet As Range
Set OntarioWestDet = DetailONW.Offset(3, 0).Resize(300)
Set OntarioEastDet = DetailONE.Offset(3, 0).Resize(300)
Set WestDet = DetailW.Offset(3, 0).Resize(300)
Set QuebecDet = DetailQc.Offset(3, 0).Resize(300)

End Sub
```